# trying to compute similarity between search terms

Tags: algorithm, text, machine-learning

I would like to compute some sort of similarity score for search queries searched on google.

This means, among other things, that the order of the words does not necessarily matter. For example:

"adidas shoes blue" and "blue shoes adidas"

should be the considered the exact same sequence, which is not the case in many of the traditional distance algorithms I believe.

The example above could be solved with cosine similarity I guess, but  what if I have:

"adiddas shoes blue"

I would like the algorithm to yield a very similar distance to the original ""adidas shoes blue"

Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. First, you request an algorithm where order of words doesn't matter (though tons exist) and then you request an algorithm which incorporates or performs spelling correction? Which of the two is your interest? Also, I think this belongs to stats or data-science stackexchange.

Comment: 1. order does not matter and 2 it accommodates similar spellings. Spelling mistakes is a thing, of course, but with brands not sure whether that works all the time. In any case, for the sake of the argument let's say that what you say is correct. I want to compute similarity scores, on the sentence as a whole, based on how similar words are where the order of the words does not matter. Regarding your second comment, there's plenty of questions like that on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Soft Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Soft_cosine_measure) and set the similarity measure between terms to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). The Soft Cosine Similarity generalizes the traditional Cosine Similarity measure by taking into account the edit distance between pairs of terms. In other words, the Soft Cosine Similarity measure compensates for the fact that the different dimensions of the vector space are not really orthogonal.

Note that you have to normalize the Levenshtein distance in such a way that similar terms have a similarity of 1 (that is, if the distance between terms is 0 then their similarity has to be 1).

More details can be found in [the paper suggesting the soft similarity measure](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/cys/v18n3/v18n3a7.pdf).